# Electron app across 2 displays?

Tags: electron

Can an electron app run one window across 2 monitors? I'm not able to drag the edge across to the other monitor. is this possible?

I know I can do this to access the second screen.

```
    const electron = require('electron')
  const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

  let win

  app.on('ready', () => {
     let displays = electron.screen.getAllDisplays()
     let externalDisplay = displays.find((display) => {
     return display.bounds.x !== 0 || display.bounds.y !== 0
   })

if (externalDisplay) {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    x: externalDisplay.bounds.x + 50,
    y: externalDisplay.bounds.y + 50
  })
  win.loadURL('https://github.com')
}
})
```

however, I dont want 2 windows just one across 2 displays.

Answer (score 2):

You can drag the electron window like any other window.

If you want to set the window size, you either do it when a `BrowserWindow` is created or via `BrowserWindow.setSize()` to modify the size [see BrowserWindow docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window)

Answer (score 2):

That was real problem, that it was impossible to set via `BrowserWindow.setSize()` values gather than height and width of first screen, to open window stretched on few screens

But finally I have found, the solution is

```
BrowserWindow.setMinimumSize(W, H);
```

that allows to set width, like 10`000px, for few monitors, and it will be applied unlike `setSize`

Comment: On Electron 19, `setMinimumSize` is working only after moving the window, but `sizeSize` is working good, i.e. it can show the window across multiple monitor whereas  `const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 10000, height: 10000})` cannot.